# Paypal Express sales_order_place_after

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, paypal-express

I encountered problem width Magento Paypal Express checkout and maybe there are more experienced programmers that could help me. What I need to do is after order is created after making payment via Paypal Express checkout I need to update sales_flat_order_grid table with some additional data in columns. I created observer that uses sales_order_place_after event. Now the problem is that sales_flat_order_grid isn't updated though both event and query I'm using to update table are correct. Maybe someone could help me sort this out? Below are my Observer files.

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <InkWorks_OrderUpdate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </InkWorks_OrderUpdate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <inkworks_orderupdate>
                <class>InkWorks_OrderUpdate_Model</class>
            </inkworks_orderupdate>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <inkworks_orderupdate>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>inkworks_orderupdate/observer</class>
                        <method>autoUpdateOrder</method>
                    </inkworks_orderupdate>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
class InkWorks_OrderUpdate_Model_Observer {
    public function autoUpdateOrder($observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="paypal_express"){
            $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
            $sql = "UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid 
                SET 
                    deliverydue = '2016-03-15 09:00',
                    kam = billing_name,
                    kur = 'Kaunas',
                    kliento_tipas = '',
                    pristatymo_budas = 'Kurjeris Lietuvoje '
                WHERE entity_id = '41'";
            $write->query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems I was right, instead of sales_order_place_after event I used sales_model_service_quote_submit_success and now it updates my new order grid. Thanks for help though, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use if condtion before your code start in observel.php

```
    $paypal_code = Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_WPP_EXPRESS;

            if($order->getPayment()->getMethod() == $paypal_code)
            {
               $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
            $sql = "UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid 
                SET 
                    deliverydue = '2016-03-15 09:00',
                    kam = billing_name,
                    kur = 'Kaunas',
                    kliento_tipas = '',
                    pristatymo_budas = 'Kurjeris Lietuvoje '
                WHERE entity_id = '41'";
            $write->query($sql);
    }
```

The above code works only paypal for payment method.

Answer (score 0):

You can save data in the table this way.

```
class InkWorks_OrderUpdate_Model_Observer {
    public function autoUpdateOrder($observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="paypal_express"){
            $model = Mage::getModel('sales/order_grid');
            $gridItem = $model->load(41);
            $gridItem
                  ->setDeliverydue('2016-03-15 09:00')
                  ->setKam('billing_name')
                  ->setKur('Kaunas')
                  ->setKilentoTipas('')
                  ->setPristatymoBudas('Kurjeris Lietuvoje')
                  ->save()
                  ;

           //test if this function is called
           Mage::log('This is called', null, 'my_observer.log');
        }
    }
}
```

**Assumption**

1. `deliverydue`, `kam`, `kur`, `kilento_tipas` and `pristatymo_budas` are already added in to the `sales_flat_order_grid` table.

After you create such order, if there is file called `my_observer.log` in `/var/log` then this function is called, otherwise it's not.

**UPDATE**

I doubt it's the `if condition` in your case not letting it do the job. You can just remove if condition and see if that works for testing.

If it works without `if` then check `class Mage_Paypal_Model_Config` and see exactly which method is fired in your case.

```
/**
 * PayPal Standard
 * @var string
 */
const METHOD_WPS         = 'paypal_standard';

/**
 * US locale
 */
const LOCALE_US = 'en_US';

/**
 * PayPal Website Payments Pro - Express Checkout
 * @var string
 */
const METHOD_WPP_EXPRESS = 'paypal_express';

/**
 * PayPal Bill Me Later - Express Checkout
 * @var string
 */
const METHOD_BML = 'paypal_express_bml';

/**
 * PayPal Website Payments Pro - Direct Payments
 * @var string
 */
const METHOD_WPP_DIRECT  = 'paypal_direct';

/**
 * Direct Payments (Payflow Edition)
 * @var string
 */
const METHOD_WPP_PE_DIRECT  = 'paypaluk_direct';

/**
 * PayPal Bill Me Later - Express Checkout (Payflow Edition)
 * @var string
 */
const METHOD_WPP_PE_BML = 'paypaluk_express_bml';

/**
 * Express Checkout (Payflow Edition)
 * @var string
 */
const METHOD_WPP_PE_EXPRESS  = 'paypaluk_express';
```

If non of above worked then something wrong with your event.

Comment: Hi Adarsh, thanks for your answer but unfortunately that does not work. I suspect that Order in grid is not populated in sales_order_place_after event. Could that be the case?

Comment: Can you place this `Mage::log('This is called', null, 'my_observer.log');` at the end of the function and see if it is fired.

Comment: Ok so it seems I was right, instead of sales_order_place_after event I used sales_model_service_quote_submit_success and now it updates my new order grid. Thanks for help though, I really appreciate it.